# Flutter: How to show a widget after every 3 rows in a gridview.count

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a banner ad widget like so

```
AdBanner()
```

in a GridView.count widget. I want the ad widget to show after every 3 rows within the grid (i.e, below every 6th item). I'm not able to get the logic. Can anyone here, please help me out? Thanks. Here is the code for my gridview

```
Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              controller: _scrollController,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 0.68,
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: items.map((Product item) {
                return Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: ProductCard(data: item));
              }).toList(),
            ),
```

I have added an image below to further explain what I mean. Though this is a listview, but if I can get it in listview, I will implement the grid. In the image, we can see a banner ad showing up after every 6th item in the list
[image]

Comment: Can you include an image of your desire output?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added the image

Comment: I think this is listView, for grid logic will be totally different, is it ok to answer just for ListView?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh You can go ahead please. Thanks

Comment: You can follow @Shaquiri1 logic, hope it will answer your question.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh See my comment on his answer. Will be glad if you can help some more. Thanks

Comment: You can check [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different approach with `GridView.builder()`

```
int ad_count = items.length ~/ 6; // divide by number of entries between every ad
int showed_ads = 0; // counter variable

GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2),
            itemCount: items.length + ad_count,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
              if((index+1)%ad_count == 0) // modulo defines the count between every ad
              {
                 showed_ads += 1;
                 return AdBanner(); // your AdBanner class here
              }
              return Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: ProductCard(data: item[index-showed_ads]));
            }),
```

Comment: This works perfectly only when I change the gridview.builder to listview.builder, but in the gridview, it hides the 6th item and doesn't show the banner ad widget of AdBanner()
See error screenshot here https://tte.metrolifetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/WhatsApp-Image-2022-01-27-at-5.01.19-AM.jpeg

Will be glad if you can help some more. Thanks

Comment: I assume that it's up to the AdBanner widget. I guess a banner can't be put into a grid cell? Perhaps you can try it with a different widget to chek if it works at all? If it only depends on the width of the widget you could try a so called [staggered grid](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view). This was used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554489/implement-admob-native-ads-in-gridview-in-fllutter) Question as well.